# Behavior of star (*) command

Tags: vim

I've noticed on occasion that that using `*` to search for the word under the cursor occasionally will have slightly different behavior (usually when I'm switching between various computers).  The issue is when I perform a search for a word that has a * in front of it (like a c++ pointer).  For example:

```
MyPointer *foo;
...
foo = new MyPointer();
```

When I move the cursor over the first occurrence of "foo", it usually does a search for that exact word (e.g. `/\<foo\>`), but sometimes it will include the `*` character in its search (e.g. `/\<*foo\>`) which causes it to fail to find any other occurrences of that variable since it's including the `*` character.

Does anyone know what causes this behavior and/or how to control it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is affected by the `isk`(`iskeyword`) option.
It may different when you switch to a different buffer.
You can type `:help 'isk'` to read more.